# How to serialize div tag's child elements by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use jQuery and ajax.

In the first. it is my html.

```
<form id="frm" name='frm' action="." method="post">
  <div style="position: absolute; top:270px;">
  <div id='mybuttons'>
    <input type="submit" class="buttonbig3" name="btn1" value="1" /><br />
    <input type="submit" class="buttonbig3" name="btn2" value="2" /><br />
  </div>
  <input id="hidden-qid" type="hidden" name="set" value="hoge" />
  </div>
</form>
```

And, I create submit function like below in JS.

```
  $('#frm').submit(function() {
var serialized_date = $('form#frm').serialize();
console.log(serialized_date);
```

However, the "console.log" logged "set" paramater.
but, btn1 or btn2 can't show the log.

I guess it is child of the mybuttons div tag.

I don't want to remove the tag. because, I create dynamically the html by javascript.

```
$('#mybuttons').innerHTML = "<input type="\submit\" class="\buttonbig3\" name=\"btn1\" value=\"1\" /><br />";
```

Could you tell me how to serialize child tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope will be helpful , just find the button that does submit and added to the serialized

```js
$('#frm').submit(function() {
  var serialized_date = $('form#frm').serialize();
  var btn = $(document.activeElement);
  serialized_date += "&" + btn.attr("name") + "=" + btn.val();
  console.log(serialized_date);
});
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frm" name='frm' action="." method="post">
  <div id='mybuttons'>
    <input type="submit" class="buttonbig3" name="btn1" value="1" /><br />
    <input type="submit" class="buttonbig3" name="btn2" value="2" /><br />
  </div>
  <input id="hidden-qid" type="hidden" name="set" value="hoge" />
</form>
```

Comment: activeElement is looks nice. Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize don't add submit button values to the data as submit buttons should be used only to submit the form, not to send specific data. You have to change the type="submit" to something else if there is specific data you want to get out of it.

Answer (score 0):

**[serialize() docs](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)**

> The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded
>   notation. It can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual
>   form controls, such as , , and : $( "input,
>   textarea, select" ).serialize();

Buttons can't be serialized. Only the elements with user inputs can be serialized like textbox, radio button, etc

If you place an input box inside the div, you will find it in your console.log.

```
 <div id='mybuttons'>
    <input type="submit" class="buttonbig3" name="btn1" value="1" /><br />
    <input type="submit" class="buttonbig3" name="btn2" value="2" /><br />
    <input id="hidden-qid" type="hidden" name="rias" value="hoge" />
 </div>
```

Now if you try submitting the form, you will get  that `input` text inside the div element. So it's not about child elements here.

Comment: Thank you for replying. But, I don't want to put the hidden element inside